# how to print jquery value in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

This is my code in jQuery, it's working fine when its alert popup, but i want to print this in html body i tried below but not working

```
// Do What You Want With Result .......... :)
$("#printermodel").change(function() {
    //'you select     
    Model = ' + $('#manufacturer').val() + 'type=' + $('#printertype').val() + 'And Model=' + $('#printermodel').val()
    alert('you select Model = ' + $('#manufacturer option:selected').text() + ' ,type= ' + $('#printertype option:selected').text() + ' And Model = ' + $('#printermodel option:selected').text());
});
});
```

```html
<div id="manufacturer"></div>
```

Comment: change your alert to $("#manufacturer").html('you select model=...')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `text` to insert text inside `div`:

```
$('#manufacturer').text($('#manufacturer option:selected').text());
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/text/

If you want to add HTML inside `div`, you can use `html` instead of `text`

Comment: i want to use in div i tried $('#manufacturer').html($('#manufacturer option:selected').text());  in html <div id="manufacturer"></div> but no result

Comment: @RaviShankar Make sure `id` is not duplicated

Comment: @RaviShankar Please create `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#manufacturer').html(('you select Model = '+
$('#manufacturer option:selected').text()+' ,type= '+
$('#printertype option:selected').text()+' And Model = '+
$('#printermodel option:selected').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take more sophisticated approach I would recommend you to use templates.
One of many options would be to use official [jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) plugin.

You need to include jquery and `http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js` plugin to your site and then you can do for example:

**Html:**

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", { "Name" : "John Doe" }).appendTo( "#target" );
```

You can adjust it to your needs and for eaxmple read the template (first parameter of `tmpl`) from some file

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb5oqd2b/)